# Get all window names within a service

Tags: c#, service

I'm trying to create a service that works as a crash detector for SRCDS (CSGO), however I am running into a few issues.

My first attempt was to create a program that monitors all windows for specific window text, but because the program is being ran through RDP, it seems to stop working after a while (it doesn't crash, it just doesn't detect anymore).

Here is the code for this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace CrashDetector
{
    class Program
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        // When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Monitoring for 'Engine Error' crash");
            System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
            {
                IntPtr handle = window.Key;
                string title = window.Value;

                if (title == "Engine Error")
                {
                    uint processid;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out processid);
                    Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)processid);
                    p.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Helper class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CrashDetector
{
    using HWND = IntPtr;

    /// <summary>Contains functionality to get all the open windows.</summary>
    public static class OpenWindowGetter
    {
        /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
        /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
        public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
        {
            HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
            Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

            EnumWindows(delegate(HWND hWnd, int lParam)
            {
                if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
                if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

                int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                if (length == 0) return true;

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

                windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
                return true;

            }, 0);

            return windows;
        }

        private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
    }
}
```

My next attempt was to create a service that will be always running, I have got the service installed and running, but it is not able to get current window titles.

Here is the code for the service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.IO;

namespace CrashDetectorService
{
    using HWND = IntPtr;

    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        // When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 5000);
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }

        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            doChecks();
        }


        private static void doChecks()
        {
            using (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
                {
                    IntPtr handle = window.Key;
                    string title = window.Value;

                    if (title == "Engine Error")
                    {
                        uint processid;
                        GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out processid);
                        Process p = Process.GetProcessById((int)processid);
                        p.Kill();
                        File.AppendAllText("C:/caught.txt", "Error caught and resolved." + Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>Contains functionality to get all the open windows.</summary>
    public static class OpenWindowGetter
    {
        /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
        /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
        public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
        {
            HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
            Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

            EnumWindows(delegate(HWND hWnd, int lParam)
            {
                if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
                if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

                int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
                if (length == 0) return true;

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
                GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

                windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
                return true;

            }, 0);

            return windows;
        }

        private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
    }

    public static class EnumerateOpenedWindows
    {
        private const int MAXTITLE = 255;

        private static List<string> lstTitles;

        private delegate bool EnumDelegate(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "EnumDesktopWindows",
            ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop,
            EnumDelegate lpEnumCallbackFunction, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowText",
            ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int _GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd,
            StringBuilder lpWindowText, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

        private static bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
        {
            string strTitle = GetWindowText(hWnd);
            if (strTitle != "" & IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) //
            {
                lstTitles.Add(strTitle);
            }
            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return the window title of handle
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWnd"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd)
        {
            StringBuilder strbTitle = new StringBuilder(MAXTITLE);
            int nLength = _GetWindowText(hWnd, strbTitle, strbTitle.Capacity + 1);
            strbTitle.Length = nLength;
            return strbTitle.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return titles of all visible windows on desktop
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of titles in type of string</returns>
        public static string[] GetDesktopWindowsTitles()
        {
            lstTitles = new List<string>();
            EnumDelegate delEnumfunc = new EnumDelegate(EnumWindowsProc);
            bool bSuccessful = EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, delEnumfunc, IntPtr.Zero); //for current desktop

            if (bSuccessful)
            {
                return lstTitles.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
// Get the last Win32 error code
                int nErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                string strErrMsg = String.Format("EnumDesktopWindows failed with code {0}.", nErrorCode);
                throw new Exception(strErrMsg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am unable to get any window titles through the service, I have tried user impersonation etc.

If you have any ideas on how I can manage to achieve this, please let me know.

Comment: I think that the service needs rights to interact with the desktop, and that is now not possible through ordinary means.  http://serverfault.com/questions/576144/allow-service-to-interact-with-desktop

Comment: Yeah, that's what I read too. Do you know of any other way I can do what I need?